# ASP.Net MVC 3 accessing CSS, JS files from separate DLL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, embedded-resource

I'm following this link, [compile razor files into separate dll](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/), and can get it to work except I can't figure out how to access JavaScript, CSS, and Images embedded in the dll.

Has anyone used this approach?  It seems very promising.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique presented in this article is for embedding razor views into separate assemblies. It doesn't allow you to do so with static resources such as images, js and CSS. For those type of resources you will have to implement a custom solution. For example you could write a controller which, given a resource name, could read it from the assembly ([GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx)) and write the stream to the response. Then you could simply generate links to this controller action in your views (`Url.Action`) and pass the resource name.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did find that MvcContrib has a feature that allows me to create a route to resources like images, js, and CSS.  I've successfully been able to retrieve js, images, css stylings in my embedded project.  It seems like I've taken aspects of Portable Areas (ala MVCContrib) and combine that with compiling my code into a separate DLL.  What's great about this is I can override a view in my parent app.  Great for flexibility.  So far it seems to work well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider](https://nuget.org/packages/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider/) which can be installed via Nuget to load all kinds of resources from referenced assemblies, and also can be set to take dependencies on the source files during development so you can update views without needing a recompile.